# Await sequentially or await a Promise.all

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I've got three promises, like so

```js
const promiseOne = factoryOne.get();
const promiseTwo = factoryTwo.get();
const promiseThree = factoryThree.get();
```

that need to be returned from a function. Is there any difference between:

```js
return [await promiseOne, await promiseTwo, await promiseThree];
```

and

```js
await Promise.all([promiseOne, promiseTwo, promiseThree])
return [promiseOne, promiseTwo, promiseThree];
```

The three promises are kicked off when they're created, so I don't *think* there will be parallelization issues. Are there any gotchas between these two approaches?

Comment: I guess the `Promise.all()` one returns synchronously and outside of the the function you can use `await` meanwhile the other does not return until all the 3 `await` for promises has not been finished.

Comment: `Promise.all()` which in itself is a `promise` gets rejected when one (any) of them fails.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference, but it's not a timing one.

In version one you're returning an array of the results of the promises (or rather, you're returning a Promise that will resolve to that array, since `async` functions always wrap the return result in an implicit Promise).

In version two you're still returning the promises, not the values to which they've resolved.   To return the results instead you'd need to use something like:

```
let result = await Promise.all([promiseOne, promiseTwo, promiseThree]);
return result;
```

There are probably also differences in the error handling of the two versions (in the event of any of those three Promises getting rejected) but I'm a little rusty on the interaction there.

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed how to modify v2 to return the values.